# Unexpected behavior when creating Scala Option from java.lang.Long

Tags: scala, null, implicit

Given following code:

```
val javaLong: java.lang.Long = null
val opt: Option[Long] = Option(javaLong)
```

I expected *opt* to be `None` but for some reason it is `Some(0)`. I also found this [bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9634) and it appears that implicit conversion happens before option's apply method.
I think this is still a bug because one wouldn't expect that behavior and  I am wondering is there any workaround or some better ways to wrap nulls.

**Update**: 
The code above is only a simplified piece. The real example is something like:

```
Person(Option(doc.getLong()))
```

where Person is:

```
 case class Person(id: Option[Long])
```

and method `doc.getLong()` is java method that returns java.lang.Long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion to `Option[Long]` is actually not just a conversion to an `Option` but also an implicit cast to `Scala`'s `Long` from `Java`'s `Long`.

```
val javaLong: java.lang.Long = null
// javaLong: Long = null

val long: java.lang.Long = javaLong
// long: Long = null
val long: Long = javaLong
// long: Long = 0
```

First we have the implicit conversion from `Java`'s `Long` to `Scala`'s `Long` which apparently produces `0` out of `null`.

Only then do we have the conversion to an `Option`.

If we specify `Java`'s `Long` as a type of our `Option` then we do get `None` and not `Some(0)`:

```
val opt: Option[java.lang.Long] = Option(javaLong)
// opt: Option[Long] = None (here it's Java's Long)
```

And we can finally cast the `Option[java.lang.Long]` to use `Scala`'s `Long`:

```
val opt: Option[Long] = Option(javaLong).map(_.toLong)
// opt: Option[Long] = None (here it's Scala's Long)
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem appears when it used in single line code in constructor. I updated the question

Comment: You might want to create an intermediate variable

Comment: I think it won't help. `val l:Long = javaLong` will produce 0. And `Option[java.lang.Long]` is not the same as `Option[Long]`

Comment: You can map the resulting `Option[java.lang.Long]` to Scala's Long: `Option(javaLong).map(_.toLong)`. `Person(Option(javaLong).map(_.toLong))` results in `Person(None)`

Comment: Thanks.`map(_.toLong)` works for me. But anyway this is strange behavior of Option :)

Comment: `Option` is working as expected, the oddity is expecting `java.lang.Long` and `Long` to be the same when one can be `null` and the other can't! You would have the same problem with any generic that tested for `null` values.